# Arc rendering bug?

Tags: svg

This is my first question so please be gentle.
I'm not a programmer and not very knowledgeable about these things.

I have been messing around with svg and raphael.js and have encountered a "problem" with rendering of arcs.

To simplify things let's forget about raphael and consider the code below:

```
<html>
<body>
    <svg width="600px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 600 400">
        <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="180" style="stroke: red; fill: none;"/>
        <line x1="200" y1="220" x2="200" y2="180" style="stroke: black"/>
        <line x1="180" y1="200" x2="220" y2="200" style="stroke: black"/>
        <path d="M200,200 L20,208 A180,180 0 0,1 378,170 z" style="stroke: blue; fill:none"/>
        <path d="M200,200 L20,208 A180,180 0 0,0 378,170 z" style="stroke: green; fill:none"/>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Assuming that the circle has been rendered correctly, I expected the two arcs to fall right on top of the circle, instead they appear offset. (Don't have enough rep to post picture.)

I have tested this in Chrome 43, Firefox 40 and Opera 30.They all produce the same outcome.

Have I misunderstood how the arc spec works? 
I also noticed that if we change the "A180,180" to "A100,100" it does not affect the result which I find rather odd.

**Update**

I'm updating the question as the information given is incomplete.
Here's the code with Raphael:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pie" style="width:600px; height:400px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var colorArr = ["#468966", "#FFF0A5", "#FFB03B"];
        var sectorAngles = [87.513812, 173.038674, 99.447514];

        var paper = Raphael("pie");

        var startAngle = 0;
        var endAngle = 90;
        var pieX = 200;
        var pieY = 200;
        var pieRadius = 180;
        var x1, y1, x2, y2;
        var arcDir = 1; //clockwise

        for (var i = 0; i < sectorAngles.length; i++) {
            startAngle = endAngle;
            endAngle = startAngle + sectorAngles[i];
            var flag = (endAngle - startAngle) > 180.0;
            x1 = Math.round( pieX + pieRadius * Math.cos(Math.PI * startAngle / 180.0) );
            y1 = Math.round( pieY + pieRadius * Math.sin(Math.PI * startAngle / 180.0) );
            x2 = Math.round( pieX + pieRadius * Math.cos(Math.PI * endAngle / 180.0) );
            y2 = Math.round( pieY + pieRadius * Math.sin(Math.PI * endAngle / 180.0) );

            var d = "M" + pieX + "," + pieY + " L" + x1 + "," + y1 + " A" + pieRadius + "," + pieRadius + " 0 " + +flag + "," + arcDir + " " + x2 + "," + y2 + " z"; 

            var arc = paper.path(d);
            arc.attr("fill", colorArr[i]);
            arc.attr("stroke-width", 0.1);
        }

        paper.circle( pieX, pieY, pieRadius ).attr({
            stroke: "red", "stroke-width": 0.2
        });           

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To be honest, i didnot know much about SVG's, but as it is fun i played with it for a while with different parameters. These changes are rendering the ARC proerply, check it: <path d="M200,200 L21,213 A180,180 0 0,1 378,170 z" style="stroke: blue; fill:none"/><path d="M200,200 L21,210 A160,168 0 0,0 378,170 z" style="stroke: green; fill:none"/> . But, please note, for the second below arc, we need to adjust/tune some  more. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red circle is centred at 200,200 and has a radius of 180.

For the two arcs to be perfectly superimposed, their endpoints (20,208 and 378,170) would need to sit exactly on the circumference of that circle.

To check, lets calculate the distance of those two points from the centre of the circle.

```
sqrt((20-200)^2 + (208-200)^2) = 180.177
sqrt((378-200)^2 + (170-200)^2) = 180.510
```

Those radius differences are enough to cause the misalignment.  If you use more accurate coordinates in your arcs, you will get better superimposition.

Note also, the green arc should have its "large-arc-flag" set because it is over 180 degrees.

```html
<svg width="600px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 600 400">
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="180" style="stroke: red; fill: none;"/>
    <line x1="200" y1="220" x2="200" y2="180" style="stroke: black"/>
    <line x1="180" y1="200" x2="220" y2="200" style="stroke: black"/>
    <path d="M200,200 L20.178,208 A180,180 0 0,1 377.482,170 z" style="stroke: blue; fill:none"/>
    <path d="M200,200 L20.178,208 A180,180 0 1,0 377.482,170 z" style="stroke: green; fill:none"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes! In the javascript, removing Math.round appears to fix the problem.